# Office 365 Azure AD issue - Single Sign On Service Not Available

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, office365

[image]I am trying to do SSO using Azure AD. I have setup my application on azure AD but on domains tab under my domain name, in field Single Sign on i get value as Not Available. How can I make it available ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare your AAD for SSOor for o365 apps. Check this KB on how to prepare, setup and troubleshoot AAD SSO issues: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2530569

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Generally we need to setup SSO for a domain to see the status for "Single Sign-On).

See my page. For me it shows "Configured" (Because I have ADFS SSO setup) and Not planned (for Managed Domains).

**For onmicrosoft.com domains, it will show "Not Available" and it is by Design logically since onmicrosoft.com is provided to you by Microsoft and we cannot do any type of SSO with that domain.**

[image]